# Authenticating user in AWS Cognito User/Identity Pool with Google as identity provider

Tags: javascript, authentication, amazon-cognito, google-signin

AWS provides two possible ways of dealing with Cognito:

1. "old one" via `amazon-cognito-identity-js` (and possibly `amazon-cognito-auth-js`) and
2. "new one" via `aws-amplify` (which inlcudes the above one)

After quite a bit of trouble and reverse engineering, I've successfully managed to sign in (receve back CognitoIdentityCredentials) using `aws-amplify` **locally** as part of the development effort.

The steps where (bear with me, as these are important for the questions to follow, and also might help someone):

### Setup

1. Create a User Pool in Cognito console
2. Create a User Pool App Client in Cognito console
3. Create Google Web App in Google Console
4. Configure Google Web App to point to http://localhost:8080 (my local dev server)
5. Configure User Pool to use Google as an Identity Provider, supplying it with the Google Web App Client ID and Client secret from Google Console
6. Create an Identity Pool in Congnito console and configure it to work with Google as an Identity Provider, supplying Google Web App Client ID there as well

### Implementation

1. Configure Amplify.Auth:

```
Amplify.configure({
    Auth: {
        identityPoolId: ,
        region: ,
        userPoolId: ,
        userPoolWebClientId: 
    }
});
```

2. Inject Google API script:

```
const script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js';
script.async = true;
script.onload = this.initGapi;
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

3. Init Google API:

```
window.gapi.load('auth2', function() {
    window.gapi.auth2.init({
        client_id: ,
        scope: 'profile email openid'
    });
});
```

4. Allow, on a button click, for a Google user to sing in:

```
const ga = window.gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
const googleUser = await ga.signIn();
const {id_token, expires_at} = googleUser.getAuthResponse();
const profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
```

5. User the `profile`, `id_token`, `expires_at` above to create a Cognito credentials session:

```
const user = {
    email: profile.getEmail(),
    name: profile.getName()
};

const credentials = await Auth.federatedSignIn(
    'google',
    {token: id_token, expires_at},
    user
);
```

At this point a `CognitoIdentityCredentials` object was returned, properly populated, with token and all...

## Problem

Unfortunately, `aws-amplify` adds a whopping **190K** to my application webpack bundle (GZIPped, minified, optimized), which made me choke on my coffee.

### Question 1

Can this somehow be reduced by a Babel plugin I'm missing (I'm guessing, no, since AWS is apparently still in 1995 and configures everything on a singleton `Amplify` and `Auth` objects).

### Question 2

Have I made this unnecessarily complicated and there is a much more robust solution?

### Question 3 (most important)

Can this be achieved using the "old way" `amazon-cognito-identity-js`, which is MUCH MUCH smaller?

I couldn't find, among all the (use cases)[https://github.com/aws/aws-amplify/tree/master/packages/amazon-cognito-identity-js/] a use case for social/federated login.

Comment: Could you give me a hand? I'm trying to implement a similar solution but i'm stuck on identity pool and i dont know how to integrate with user pool

Comment: @placplacboom There is a setting, on user pool (after it is created), that let's you define an identity pool. In my case I configured Google, so I had to provide an ID, which I got from Google Developer Console. You have to create an app there, which will then allow you to configure an identity provider.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the difference between

```
import Amplify from 'aws-amplify'
```

and

```
import Amplify from '@aws-amplify/core'
```

is ~500kB optimized and minified.

I think you also want

```
import Auth from '@aws-amplify/auth'
```

which adds only a little bit more.

But I agree, the aws-amplify package is really very large and it's not easy to figure out how to use the core components directly (e.g. aws-cognito-identity-js/es and aws-cognito-auth-js/es).

Answer (score -1):

You could try using modularized exports in AWS amplify

Comment: Care to elaborate, perhaps with an example?  The more context you give, the more it will make sense to others.